# Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object powershell script

Tags: powershell, acl

I need to check the box for **"Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object"** in the below image

[image]

I tried the below codes but not getting the expected output

```
# Define the folder path
$folderPath = "H:\"

# Get the existing access control list (ACL) for the folder
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $folderPath

# Enable inheritance and clear existing explicit permissions
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false, $true)

# Apply the modified ACL to the folder and all its subdirectories
Set-Acl -Path $folderPath -AclObject $acl -Recurse -Force

Write-Host "Inheritable permissions have been applied to all child objects in $folderPath."
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: The equivalent would to protect the rules and not preserve inheritance, eg. [`$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: thanks for your response. I checked it. getting error in `set-acl`
**Set-Acl : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Recurse'.**